# Como aumentar el valor de una celda de un DataGridView cuando coincida un codigo? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy haciendo una especie de verificador, necesito que al presionar un boton verifique si el codigo de mi TextBox coincide en algun dato de la columna "Codigo" y de ser asi, aumente en 1 el valor de "Capturado" , esto es lo que estoy intentado ahora:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (fila.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == txtCodigo.Text)
            {
                int n = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells[3].Value);
                n = n + 1;
                fila.Cells[3].Value = n;
            }
        }
```

Y esta es la imagen de mi tabla [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que me marca este error en la ejecucion del programa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pudieran ayudar a ubicar mi error se los agradeceria mucho, soy algo nuevo en esto , gracias de antemano

Comment: En donde estas llamando a la función? prueba reemplazar `fila.Cells[0].Value.ToString()`  por  `fila.Cells["Codigo"].Value.ToString()` "Codigo" debe ser el nombre real de tu columna en el datasource.

Comment: @FranIslas la estoy llamando en un boton, todo ese codigo esta dentro de la accion de un boton ( no se ve en la imagen de la tabla) probare lo que dices, muchas gracias

Update: lo cheque como mencionaste y marca el mismo error

Comment: Muestra tu codigo un poco arriba

Comment: La función completa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo he probado y la función está intentando acceder a la fila que hay abajo del todo del grid, la que se supone que es para crear una nueva fila.

Como en la celda 0, no hay ningún valor, cuando intenta aplicar el ToString al valor, da el error. Podrías solucionarlo con el código que te indico, que obvia la fila cuando el valor de la celda es nulo.

Espero que te sirva.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (fila.Cells[0].Value != null){
                if (fila.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == txtCodigo.Text)
                {
                    int n = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells[3].Value);
                    n = n + 1;
                    fila.Cells[3].Value = n;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```